# Form Select on submit run a function

Tags: php, html, forms

```
    <form action="" method="post">  
    <select name="answer" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
        <option>Choose Answer</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

I want to cal a function after user chooses 1 answer.
Function gets input the selected value. for example answered($option_here)

Comment: `onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"`

Comment: You need to specify that the function you want to call is a PHP function. Wasn't at all clear from the question in my opinion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the function call to the onchange attribute.

```
onchange="answered(this.value);this.form.submit();"
```

Edit:

Sorry, misunderstood your question. I though `answered` was a JavaScript function.

You have `POST` as your form method, so when it is submited you have to use `$_POST` to get the data, not `$_GET`. Try this instead:

```
answered( $userid, $answerid, $_POST["answer"] );
```

Comment: Do you have an `answered` function defined?

Comment: yes. its actually answered(userid, answerid, this.value) and makes db insert on that function.

Comment: and I use $_GET to get the userid, answereid from a previus page

Comment: Is this a PHP function or JavaScript function?

Comment: this doesnt work: onchange="answered($_POST["answer"]);this.form.submit();"

Comment: You need to call answered from your PHP script where you submitted the form to, not in the HTML. Change the onchange attribute back to `onchange="this.form.submit()"`.

Comment: ok thanks I know this. I though I could do it like js function that you don't have to call a .php page. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you submit the form when the user selects anything, which it looks like you do, you can just handle it like you would any other form being submitted.

If you want to do it without reloading the page you have to use Javascript and AJAX. And if so, you might find some pointers in this sample code: http://samples.geekality.net/tail. This posts some data using jQuery Ajax to a php file which then calls a function and returns some result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this one:

```
<script>
    function doSmTh(ths)
    {
        /*some actions*/

        document.forms['formName'].submit();
    }
</script>

     <form action="" id="formName" name="formName" method="post">  
        <select name="answer" onchange="doSmTh(this)" >
            <option>Choose Answer</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
     </form>
```